# Java stream: How to group by a keyword?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a text file that looks like

```
Group: A 
12
27 
14 
Group: B 
68
10 
42
79
Group: D
...
```

I want to compute statistics for the list of numbers of each group.

**Question:** Is there a good way to do this with Java streams?

Nb: I know that, given an `IntStream`, the statistics can be obtained by applying method `summaryStatistics`. My problem is that I don't know how to group the elements below the keyword "Group:".

**Added:** Concerning the somewhat strange comments: Without streams the problem could be solved by

```
   String group = null;  
   boolean first = true; 
   List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); 
   for (String s: lines) { 
     if (s.startsWith("Group:") { 
       if (!first) { 
         System.out.println(group + " sum: " + sum); 
       }  
       first = false; 
       group = s; 
       sum = 0; 
     } else { 
       sum += Integer.parseInt(s.strip()); 
     }
   }
   System.out.println(group + " sum: " + sum);
```

Comment: This requires a *stateful* functor. I would use one in `collect()`ing, but I don't remember whether stateful functors are legal in the Stream API.

Comment: Why the downvote? There are many text files like this in practise. As explained, it is straight forward to write down a solution by using loops. But I hope there is a simpler solution with streams. That's the reason for the question and this reason is clearly stated either in the title ("Java stream") and the question ("do this with Java streams").

Comment: Accodring to [Java Documentation on `collect` and friends](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-), functors need to be *stateless*, i.e., it can't be done with streams only, in my opinion. You may want to first use plain loops (or other libraries) to group the elements in a `Map` and then stream the Entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I put the data in an array for a demo.

```
        String[] vals = {
                "Group: A ",
                "12       ",
                "27       ",
                "14       ",
                "Group: B ",
                "68       ",
                "10       ",
                "42       ",
                "79       ",
                "Group: D ",
                "10       ",
                "20       ",
                "30       ", 
                "18       ",
                "12       "
                };
```

Grouping the data in the map was a simple matter of capturing the `Group` tag and then add values to a `List` value for that tag.  The data is trimmed of white space prior to processing and the appropriate strings are converted to integers.
Because of the asynchronous nature of the data, I could not figure a more concise way of doing it.  Others may have better ideas.

```
        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();


        List<Integer> numbs = null;
        for (String v : vals) {
            v = v.trim();
            if (v.startsWith("Group")) {
                // add a new List and save its reference
                map.put(v, numbs = new ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                // add using current object
                numbs.add(Integer.valueOf(v));
            }
        }
```

In the second step I just created a map of summary stats keyed on the group id.

```
        Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> results = 

                map.entrySet()

                // stream of entryset
                .stream()
                // put them in a map
                .collect(Collectors
                      .toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey(),
                        // generate summary stats for each list by 
                        // streaming the list and collecting the values
                        e -> e.getValue()
                           .stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(r->r))));

results.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Group: A=IntSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=53, min=12, average=17.666667, max=27}
Group: B=IntSummaryStatistics{count=4, sum=199, min=10, average=49.750000, max=79}
Group: D=IntSummaryStatistics{count=5, sum=90, min=10, average=18.000000, max=30}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Fureeish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7151494) mentioned, streams are not suitable for stateful operations. However, **serial** processing can turn your multiple lines of each group into a line per group, so that (`src/temp.txt`):

```
Group: A 
12
27 
14 
Group: B 
68
10 
42
79
Group: D
98
187
894
67
Group: G
3
3
Group: G
5
5
```

becomes this:

```
Group:A 12 27 14
Group:B 68 10 42 79
Group:D 98 187 894 67
Group:G 3 3
Group:G 5 5
```

in a `List` of `String`, by adding a newline character in front of every `Group: X`, trimming all spaces, and then joing all Strings. Then you can stream the list in a stateless manner and map each group to a `IntSummaryStatistics`:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StackOverflowTest {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Path path = Path.of("src/temp.txt");

    try {
      // transform the Strings by adding a newline to Strings matching the group characteristics
      List<String> transformed =
        Files.readAllLines(path)
             .stream()
             .map(s -> s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*:.*") ? 
                                 "\n" + s.replace(" ","") : s.trim())
             .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))  // one long string
             .lines()                           // split according to the newline
             .skip(1)                           // don't want the first empty line
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println("Transformed list:\n" + transformed);

      System.out.println();

      // map the transformed list to the individual groups with their own IntSummaryStatistics
      Map<String,IntSummaryStatistics> mapSummary =
        transformed
             .stream()
             .map(s -> s.split("\\s"))
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0],         // first index is the group
                                       s -> IntStream.range(1, s.length)
                                                     .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(s[i]))
                                                     .summaryStatistics(),
                                       (a, b) -> {a.combine(b); return a;}
                                       )
                     );
      System.out.println("Mapping statistics:\n" + mapSummary);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Oops: " + ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Result (cheated by added newlines):

```
Transformed list:
[Group:A 12 27 14 , Group:B 68 10 42 79 , Group:D 98 187 894 67 , Group:G 3 3 , Group:G 5 5]

Mapping statistics:
{
Group:B=IntSummaryStatistics{count=4, sum=199, min=10, average=49.750000, max=79},
Group:A=IntSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=53, min=12, average=17.666667, max=27},
Group:G=IntSummaryStatistics{count=4, sum=16, min=3, average=4.000000, max=5},
Group:D=IntSummaryStatistics{count=4, sum=1246, min=67, average=311.500000, max=894}
}
```